# How to use opencv bundle adjustment

Tags: opencv, camera, mathematical-optimization, camera-calibration

I have calculated 5 camera matrices (`c1, ... c5`), camera matrices are calculated by placing a 3D object at 5 different positions and for each position I have calculated camera matrix (and camera is constant). Camera matrix is calculated using SVD method.

Now I want to use bundle adjustment in `opencv` to get one optimal camera matrix. 
I found the documentation [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/stitching/doc/motion_estimation.html?highlight=bundleadjust#detail::BundleAdjusterBase%20:%20public%20detail::Estimator)

But documentation is not clear and also I was not able to find any sample code. 
Can anybody explain how can I use opencv bundle adjustment to get the `optimal camera matrix` ?

Comment: Your question does not make much sense, because the bundle adjustment technique is normally used to jointly estimate the pose (i.e. T=[R|t] describing the orientation and position) of multiple cameras frames and the 3D position of some observed points. To estimate the camera matrix (i.e. K, the matrix of intrinsics parameters) you would normally use a calibration procedure, such as the one explained [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html#cameracalibrationopencv).

Comment: @AldurDisciple bundle adjustment is not limited to refining pose, you could definitely add the equations for refining K too. OpenCV's code does so. Though there is a mask that can be used to specify what members of K you want to optimize, or none.

Comment: @fireant true, and good news if OpenCV supports it. But it's still unclear from the question whether the OP mentioned Bundle Adjustment on purpose or just as a way to do a joint optimization. It's worth noting that the `calibrateCamera` function was designed to be more general than the standard calibration pattern case and that it can also handle abstract 3D patterns.

Answer (score 17):

My answer assumes that you use a specific 3D object, whose dimensions are known *accurately*, to estimate the intrinsic parameters of *one camera* from *multiple images* of the object. In light of your comment to @fireant 's answer, I think this applies to your question.

## Quick note on the meanings of 'camera matrix'

The term 'camera matrix' is very vague and can be understood in multiple ways:

- The camera pose T = [R|t], also denoted extrinsic camera parameters.
- The intrinsic camera matrix K = [fx, s, cx; 0, fy, cy; 0, 0, 1].
- The camera projection matrix P = K.[R|t].

As you say that you have multiple images but you want a single camera matrix, I think that you are talking about the intrinsic camera matrix K.

## Why you should not use Bundle Adjustment

Bundle Adjustment is a technique used to solve a more general problem than camera calibration, where both the extrinsic camera parameters (i.e. 3D orientations and positions) and the 3D landmarks (e.g. 3D points) are unknown. As @fireant noted, it is also possible to include intrinsic camera parameters in this global joint optimization. On the other hand, camera calibration assumes the 3D landmarks are known and observed by a single camera in multiple images, therefore it optimizes a single set of intrinsic camera parameters and one camera pose for each image.

The thing to understand is that more general optimization problems involve more variables to be optimized, and it is therefore harder to make them well-constrained. If they are not well-constrained, they will optimize your variables in a way that indeed decrease the global error, but that does not correspond to a solution of your real problem. This is why, when using a joint optimization algorithm, you should always try to reduce the number of variables to be optimized.

In the case of Bundle Adjustment VS Camera Calibration, you should only use Bundle Adjustment if you have **no accurate idea** of positions of the 3D landmarks. Even then, it is probably a better idea to try and decouple the problems, for instance by calibrating the 3D object beforehand. If you do have an accurate idea of the positions of the 3D landmarks, then they should not be considered as variables to be optimized, hence you should use the Camera Calibration technique.

## Initial estimate for the optimization

You are saying that you have multiple inaccurate estimates of the camera matrix K, and want to perform a joint optimization to obtain a single more accurate one. The problem is that, since you want to estimate a single camera matrix, you need to provide the joint optimization algorithm with **only one initial estimate**.

What you could do, in order to still use your multiple approximate estimates, is to try to select, as initial estimate for the optimization algorithm, the one closest to the true solution. For this purpose, you can use several heuristic criteria. For example you can select the one associated with the minimum reprojection error, or you can use the one associated to the image where the calibration object is the largest, etc.

However, it will probably not make a big difference in the final estimate of the camera matrix.

## How to use 'calibrateCamera' for this task

Suppose you have a calibration object with characteristic points. It can be a standard 2D chessboard or assymetric circle grid, or any calibrated 3D object. And suppose you have developped a way to detect this calibration object in an image (e.g. a custom feature detector, or a tool to manually determine the position of the object). Then you can define a vector `allObjectPoints`, containing the 3D points on the object that can be detected. Then for each image `i`, you can determine a vector `imagePoints_i` of the 2D points detected to be observations of some the object's 3D points (note that some object points may be occluded, hence there may be less items than in `allObjectPoints`). Then, since all the object points are identifiable (either directly or by reasoning), you can determine the vector `objectPoints_i`, containing the object 3D points actually observed in image `i` and ordered consistantly with `imagePoints_i`.

Then you stack all the `objectPoints_i` vectors in one big vector of vectors `objectPoints`. Similarly you stack all the `imagePoints_i` vectors in one big vector of vectors `imagePoints`. You can then make the call to `calibrateCamera`, with the flag `CV_CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS` to indicate that you want the optimization algorithm to use the initial value that you provided.

Answer (score 10):

See the sample code at page 155 of [Learning Image Processing with OpenCV](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1783287659). Something like this:

```
vector<CameraParams> cameras;
vector<MatchesInfo> pairwise_matches;
vector<ImageFeatures> features(num_images);

// initialize the above params here

Ptr<BundleAdjusterBase> adjuster;
adjuster = makePtr<BundleAdjusterReproj>();
if (!(*adjuster)(features, pairwise_matches, cameras)) {
    cout << "Camera parameters adjusting failed." << endl; 
    return -1;
}
```

If you provide a MCVE then it's easier to help.

**Edit:**
Given you have 5 estimates of the same K matrix. The easiest method is to simply average your 5 estimations to get a more accurate K. Under some mild assumptions that will be an optimal estimation. If the reprojection errors vastly differ, then you can calculate a weighted average.

Comment: I think, in this example each camera matrix is optimized. How I can get a single final camera matrix ??.

Comment: @user_12 it seems i misunderstood your question. see my edit.